# What's the function of 到 in 今天的考试要用到词典?

Tags: meaning

When I was reading a text, I encountered this sentence:

> 今天的考试要用到词典，请大家把词典也放在桌子上。

I know what the whole sentence means but what's the function of 到 in this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

到 is used as this sense defined in dictionaries:

> 用在动词后，表示动作结果。
>   Used after a verb, [it] expresses the result of an action.

It functions a *resultative complement* in your sentence.

Comment: Maybe it's also appropriate to add the Chinese Grammar Wiki reference: [Result complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Result_complement).